# Every Lebesgue integrable function is real valued almost every where

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I found this comment in my notes from a probability course I was taking, which I have doubts on (I'm not sure if I have the statement written down correctly). It states: every Lebesgue integrable function is real valued $\mu$-almost everywhere.
I think I have a counter-example: take a uniform random variable $X$ defined on an interval $[a,b]$, its characteristic function is $$\mathbb E[e^{itX}] = \int e^{itx} d\mathbb P(x) = \int_a^b \frac{e^{itx}}{b-a} dx = \frac{e^{itb} - e^{ita}}{it(b-a)}.$$ But in this case the function being integrated is  not real-valued a.e.. Is my counter-example wrong or the original statement wrong?

Comment: I think this statement holds for $[0,+\infty]$-valued functions that you use when establishing the theory, not for complex-valued ones.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, to make sure I understand, do you mean since we defined the integral using real-valued function, the statement holds but it does not say anything about complex-valued function?

Comment: Yes, I think a similar statement for a "Lebesgue complex function" $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ with $u$ and $v$ $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued would be "$f$ is integrable implies $u$ and $v$ are real valued almost everywhere", meaning that the sets $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,;\,|u(z)|=+\infty\}$ and $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,;\,|v(z)|=+\infty\}$ have measure $0$.

Comment: The constant function $f (x) = \sqrt{-1}$ is measurable and integrable too....

Comment: @Balloon, thank you.